# How can I pass the local value of a foreach of a function in the argument of another function(no events)?

Tags: javascript, html

Guys I wanted to open an iframe with a youtube video by pressing on an image but the carregaVideo() function is not able to get the value of "i" from the oioi() function. how can i change the code for the carregaVideo() function get the value of "i" from the oioi() function without using events. The BDVYT array has 25 elements, I just added two for simplicity.

```js
var BDVYT = [
    {refa:"dv9h6klKCLE",},{refa:"pnv5rYXmaJs",},
        ];

var refEcran;

function inic(){
    oioi();
}

refEcran = document.getElementById("ecran");

function execYT(codYT){
    var codHTML = '';
    codHTML += '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" ';
    codHTML += 'src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/';
    codHTML += codYT;
    codHTML += '?"></iframe>';
    refEcran.innerHTML = codHTML;
}

function carregaVideo(){
    execYT(BDVYT[i].refa);          
}

function oioi(){
        var refItems = document.querySelectorAll('#item');
            
   refItems.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.innerHTML = '<div id="itemImag"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/'
        + BDVYT[i].refa + '/mqdefault.jpg" onclick="carregaVideo()" width="100%" /></div>
    });                 
}
```

```html
<body onload="inic()">


<div id="item"></div>
<div id="item"></div>


<div id="ecran"></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as an argument:

```js
 refItems.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.innerHTML = '<div id="itemImag"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/'
        + BDVYT[i].refa + '/mqdefault.jpg" onclick="carregaVideo(' + i + ')" width="100%" /></div>'
    });
```

And define the parameter as well:

```js
function carregaVideo(i){
    execYT(BDVYT[i].refa);          
}
```